# template field issue in the gridview

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, gridview, templatefield

Q:

I have the following problem , and i don't know how to fix it really.

I have a `grid view` one of the columns is a `template field` as (text box). The grid view consists of `8` rows . What i do is every time the user enter data in the text box,I put the total in the last text box(which set enabled = false).I sum the data entry in the text boxes through some method and call it in the event `text changed` . But every time i enter a number in the text box and then click `Tab in the keyboard` or use the mouse cursor to move to the next box i lose the focus , and i have to put the mouse cursor again in the intended textbox.

I try the following methods to fix my problem but in vain .

```
 foreach (GridViewRow r in gv_Evaluation.Rows)
            {
                ((RadTextBox)r.Cells[3].FindControl("txt_evaluateWeights")).Attributes.Add("blur", "calc()");
            }
```

in my page load , this doesn't work at all.

---

```
protected void txt_evaluateWeights_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    calc();
    ((TextBox)sender).Focus();
}
```

This way return the focus to the previous textbox (i mean the one which i already have done) not the text box i wanna the focus in, to enter the data.

**EDIT:**

My calc method:

```
private void calc()
        {
            float sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                RadTextBox txt1 = (RadTextBox)gv_Evaluation.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("txt_evaluateWeights");
                int weight;
                bool result = Int32.TryParse(txt1.Text, out weight);
                if (result)
                {
                    sum += weight;
                }
            }

            double percentage;
            percentage = Math.Round((sum / 100) * 100, 2);
            RadTextBox txt3 = (RadTextBox)gv_Evaluation.Rows[7].Cells[3].FindControl("txt_evaluateWeights");
            txt3.Text = percentage.ToString();//string.Format("{0:0.0%}", percentage.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: can you post what your `calc` function also?

Comment: Do you want to PostBack and calculate the sum on serverside or do you want to do it on clientside? Also, have you considered the problems when Paging is enabled and some of the rows don't exist on clientside at all? What do you mean with "put the total in the last text box", last TextBox in row or f.e. in the Footer?

Comment: Firstly:The gridview is in an `update panel`.
Secondly:I wanna to make the calculation on `server side` because i store them in my database.
Thirdly:`no paging` , just eight rows because ,iam the one who structure the datatable which is the datasource.
fourthly:the last textbox in the `row` number eight not in the footer.

Comment: why are you assigning your cal to the eighth row?

Comment: i wanna , every time the user enter number in the text box the total calculated in the last textbox and the focus move to the next text box .not lost as my case.

Comment: my problem is in losing my focus every time textbox changed.

Comment: @just_name: I'm not sure i understand what you mean by: But every time i enter a number in the text box and then click Tab in the keyboard or use the mouse cursor to move to the next box i lose the focus , and i have to put the mouse cursor again in the intended textbox. :)

Comment: i mean :the user wanna to evaluate set of courses.one textbox for each course. the user enter an evaluation for the first course .and the total is calculated in the last textbox. now when the user click `tab` in the keyboard to move to the next text box to evaluate the next course . the focus is lost . and have to click in the text box agian to evaluate it??!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it using server side PostBack is a horrendous way of doing this.

Use JavaScript instead. Here is a small example in jQuery

The GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="DemoGrid" runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="index">
            <ItemTemplate><%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="DemoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>Total</FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="DemoText" runat="server" CssClass="quantity">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="TotalLabel" runat="server" CssClass="result"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string[] array = new string[] { "demo1", "demo2", "demo3", "demo4", "demo5" };
        DemoGrid.DataSource = array;
        DemoGrid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The JavaScript (jQuery)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".quantity").bind("blur", function () {
            var $quantity = $(this);
            var quantity = +$quantity.val(); //cast to number
            if (!isNaN(quantity)) {
                var $sum = $quantity.closest("table").find("tr:last .result");
                var sum = +$sum.html();
                $sum.html(sum + quantity);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps